# Is it possible to convert garbled text from Access into a readable format?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an Access .mdb file. When I open it there are some text entries which are not in English. It contains lots of strange characters like this.

> µ²e¡³»»r´ºÁ®t¾ÄÅ¹qm¦À¾o¡¶

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of DB font]

I need this in a readable format. So my question is, is it possible to convert this thing into a readable format?

Comment: Are these character your data? What version of access are you using to open the file?

Comment: Yes, those characters are from my data. I am using 2013 version. I opened the same file in MDB plus too. Same characters are showing.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of my DB.

Comment: Have you tried doing a "Compact and Repair Database" operation on a copy of the .mdb file? It's a long shot, but it's at least worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database is corrupted and there may not be much that can be done. However, try the following before giving up.

- Check your tables and see if the data in the tables are readable
- Create a new database and import all your table in the new database and see if it is readable

Comment: But there are other tables which are in readable format. Only 2-3 tables are in other symbols.

Comment: If you have tried Gord and my suggestions without success then things are not looking good. However have a look at this link which refer to several repair tools http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/repair-corrupt-access-database-file/ I'd be interested in to know if anyone of them works